# Adding Number increments to Variables

Tags: shell, unix, while-loop, ksh

I have a file which has `N` number of lines. I need to read each line and store it in a variable.
For example, Firstline in var1, Secondline in var2, etc.

I tried the below `while` loop,

```
count=1;
while read line  
do  
var$count=`echo $line`  
echo -e "$var`$count`"  
done< input.txt
```

In the above code, I am hitting error in the last but one line above!.

How to Reference a variable with another referenced variable?

Here, I am just echoing but actually I want the values stored in the variables to do some arithmetic calculations(like calculating time average).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array in bash or ksh:

```
array=( $(< input.txt) )

echo ${array[0]} # first element
echo ${array[1]} # second element

echo ${#array[*]} # length
```

See [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html).

Comment: First, the question is tagged 'ksh'. Second, constructing an array this way splits the input file by words (whitespace), not by line.

Comment: The way the OP was trying to tackle the problem didn't suggest he had very much experience and his choice of using ksh may not therefore have been very well informed and bash is a very good fit for the problem. If he MUST use ksh, he is welcome to apply the concept in his preferred shell. I agree with your second point, and the example in my answer will quickly show the OP how my answer works so he can ask if he wants it read differently. My answers aren't always prescriptive and absolute, sometimes I am just providing a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Also, the question title implies each line is a number that the OP wants to add to, so my method of reading should be fine.

Comment: I agree that I'd choose bash over ksh any day. No idea where all these ksh question come from, actually. If it's really just numbers, the ``array=($(cat input.txt))`` solution will even work in ksh, good catch.

Answer (score 4):

As Mark Setchell noted, arrays are the preferable solution. They are available in KSh too:

```
set -A lines
count=1
while read line; do
    lines[$count]=$line
    echo -e ${lines[$count]}
    count=$(( $count + 1 ))
done < input.txt
```

For more details, take a look at this [simple introduction with examples](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ksh-array-iteration-examples-using-for-loop/), or [this chapter](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch06_04.htm) from O'Reilly's "Learning the Korn Shell" book.

Comment: where do you increment `count`?

Comment: My bad. Fixed the example.